# How to prevent Simulink from storing every time step inside a data store block?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simevents

I have a data store block (let's say 20x5000 array), it is used for generating a schedule. 
The simulation uses SimEvents blocks.
Every time step it's being updated.
The problem is that it generates a 3-D array (the third one is the time steps), and I only want a 2-D array. I don't need the evolution of it.
How do I prevent Simulink from keeping the history of all the steps?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it was more simple that I thought. 
In the block "To Workspace", I have set the value of "limit data points to last" to 1.